Efficiently Retrieving Pardot Users Based on Email Domains from a Large External List
I have an external list containing over 1500 accounts, and I need to identify Pardot users whose email domains match those in this list. Unfortunately, Pardot doesn't provide a native function for querying users based on external data sources.
Desired Outcome
I want to generate a comprehensive list of Pardot users whose email domains align with the domains in my external account list.
Constraints
Data Volume: The external list has over 1500 accounts.
Pardot Limitations: Pardot doesn’t offer a direct method to query users based on external data sources.
Potential Workarounds for Small Datasets
For small datasets, you could:
Dynamic Lists: Create dynamic lists with filters based on email domains (e.g., Email Like '%@example.com%'). However, this is limited by the number of dynamic lists allowed in Pardot.
Automation Rules: Set up automation rules with criteria based on email domains. But managing many automation rules becomes impractical for large lists.
Recommended Approach for Large Datasets
For a large list, I’m considering using a data integration platform to:
Extract email domains from the external list.
Compare these domains with Pardot user email domains.
Generate a list of matching Pardot users.
Questions
Recommended Platforms: What are the recommended data integration platforms for handling large datasets and Pardot integration?
Pardot API: Are there known limitations or best practices for using the Pardot API to retrieve user information based on email domains?
I would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations on the most effective approach to tackle this challenge.
